# IE HTTPS Ajax request image not showing up

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, image

In IE (7 or 8) and HTTPS mode, following RESPONSE is delivered for an AJAX request. My issue is the img was NOT requested at all by IE (figured out using Fiddler), broken img is shown instead. It all works perfectly in HTTP mode in IE and other browsers no problem rendering in both mode (please don't tell me not to use IE). Any thoughts/work-arounds/suggestions? Thanks.

```
<div>
   <h1>Chart Title</h1>
   <h2>Chart sub-title</h2>
   <img src="https://www.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:106,169,73,14&chds=0,169&chs=300x150&chtt=Ocean+Area&chdl=Atlantic|Pacific|Indian|Arctic&chma=0,0,0,0|70&chco=3366CC|DC3912|FF9900|109618&chp=4.7">
   <p>message comes here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: running that image url in IE8 does return an image for me, but in my case (of all things, quicktime grabbed the response... and rendered the image centered in my browser window)... (after disabling quicktime, I too get a "broken image"...odd because firebug(in Firefox) indicates the Content-Type returned is image/png)

Comment: How is that content added to the DOM?

Comment: jQuery Tab UI, adds this content to the DOM.

Comment: My current status is that the issue is very specific to cross domain image. If I add current domain image...it works.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth checking that this isn't being caused by a corrupt DOM: try closing the img tag in the AJAX response and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried both closing and not-closing...either way it is not working.